# All the ways to start flash from a PHP website

Tags: javascript, php, html, flash

I don't know much of anything about developing with flash. I am maintaining a website that used to have some flash, but now I don't think it is used anymore. I found some swf files still hanging around in the repository. I would like to delete them, but first I am checking to make sure they are not used anywhere. The rest of the website is just PHP, html, and javascript. What are all the ways flash can be used/started from within that context? In other words, what should I look out for to see if it is still being used?

Are flash files just referenced from within HTML/DOM?

Comment: Do up a script that will find all instances of `.swf` in files. `glob()` will come in handy, and `strpos()` - `preg_match()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hmm. I did create a script that searches for `.swf`. It found a LOT of matches, since there are quite a few js libraries we are using that contain that text. It would be difficult to be sure none of those features of those libraries are being used. I did confirm that '.swf' only appears in those libraries. I don't think the website uses flash anywhere. I guess I will just delete the files and if it breaks something I'm sure someone will complain at some point. I can always recover the files from the git repository history.

Comment: If you can, you can always rename and hide the folder(s) in question, or make a copy of them somewhere. I always make copies on my own machine etc. so yeah, if something goes haywire, you'll have something to take from your logs and see where the 404's will be coming from.